# windows kernel debugging on Mac host (using VirtualBox)

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I'm running on MacOS Sierra (version 10.12.4). And I created two virtual machine on Virtualbox (version 5.1.22).

1- Host Machine : Windows 10 Pro x64 (I installed Windows Driver kit 10)

2- Target Machine: Windows 7 Pro x64

Now I'm trying to use the first machine to debug the second one. And I configured the same host pipe for the two machines.

- Configuration for the serial port in the Host machine(also same in the Target machine)[image]
- In the debugger (host) machine, I launches windbg with this settings

[image]

- And I enabled debug mode on the debugee (target) machine

> C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit/dbgsettings
>
> debugtype               Serial
>
> debugport               1
>
> baudrate                115200

But when I trying to connect, they don't seem to know each other.

What's wrong?

Comment: I don't know about MacOS host. But in Windows you have to map the com ports to the same named pipe in the Virtual Box. And, make sure one and only one of the virtual machines create the named pipe on startup

Answer (score 1):

1. Start **Debugger** VM at first.

   ```
   WinDbg: com:port=com1,baud=115200
   ```
2. Start **Debuggee** VM at second, and **Enable Kernel Debug Mode**.

   ```
   C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit /copy {current} /d "Windows Kernel Exploitation"   
   .... {bee4606e-51f1-11e8-97a8-decf25840cbf}

   C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit /debug {bee4606e-51f1-11e8-97a8-decf25840cbf} on   

   C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit /dbgsettings  
   debugtype               Serial   
   debugport               1  
   baudrate                115200
   ```

---

**Debuggee**

[image: Windows Kernel Debuggee]

**Debugger**

[image: Windows Kernel Debugger]

[image: Windows Kernel WinDbg Output]

Comment: I found different way when I have this problem. Than, it works..But I  will try again asap. Thank you again.

Comment: VirtualBox is slow for windows kernel debug, maybe you can try another vm platform(ex, Vmware, VirtualFD).